# Exchange EWS MailItem shows attachment but doesn't let me retrieve the fileattachment

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to load a file attachment (its an image file) from an exchange email.

`
foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults.Items)
            {
                if (item.HasAttachments)
                {
                    var something = item.Attachments[0];

```
                foreach (Attachment attachment in item.Attachments)
                {
                    if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                    {
                        FileAttachment fattach = (FileAttachment)attachment;`
```

For some reason, even though the item has an attachment (I can confirm this by logging into the web interface), it does not allow me to retrieve the fileattachment.

It shows up as null.   Why would an item have an attachment in the collection BUT not have it be retrievable?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that not all properties are set, so you need to call LoadPropertiesForItems method from the Exchange service itself to load the extra data like attachments.
for example if you want to load all the attachments of the item x and the exchange service instance is s then:

```
List<Item> xlist = new List<Item>();
            xlist.Add(x);
            s.LoadPropertiesForItems(xlist,PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

When binding to the Item, you need to specify the Attachments property. The following code sample should help:

```
PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Attachments);    
Item item = Item.Bind(service, itemId, propertySet);
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed to load the attachment. Please see the below example for idea

```
EmailMessage msgInfo = null;
foreach (Item msgItemInfo in msgItemWithNotification)
{
   msgInfo = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, msgItemInfo.Id);
   foreach (Attachment attachment in msgInfo.Attachments)
       {
           if( attachment is FileAttachment)
              {
                  FileAttachment fattach = attachment as MSEWS.FileAttachment;
                  fattach.Load();
                  Stream excelFileStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fattach.Content);
              }
       }
}
```